# How to input Double variables?

Tags: java

When I run this code and input the double value for the first variable i.e 
miles It shows an error on the read.nextDouble() line as Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException.

```
/**
 * Created by Ranjan Yadav on 1.10.2016.
 */
public class GasMileage {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.util.Scanner read = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Miles Driven(press 1 to quit): ");
        double miles = read.nextDouble();
        double totalGalon = 0;
        double totalMiles = 0;
        double milesPerGalon = 0;
        double totalMilesPerGalon = 0;
        totalMiles += miles;
        while(miles != 1){
            System.out.println("Gallon used: ");
            double galon = read.nextDouble();
            counter++;
            milesPerGalon = miles / galon;
            totalMilesPerGalon += milesPerGalon;
            System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + milesPerGalon);
            System.out.println("Miles Driven(press 1 to quit); ");
            miles = read.nextDouble();
            totalGalon += galon;
            totalMiles += miles;
        }
        if(counter == 0 ){
            System.out.println("No values were entered.\nThanks for Using!\n\n");
        }else{
            double avg = totalMilesPerGalon / counter;
            System.out.printf("Total miles driven: %.2f" , totalMiles);
            System.out.printf("Total gallons used: %.2f" , totalGalon);
            System.out.printf("Miles per gallon for all trips: %.2f" , totalMilesPerGalon);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you inputting?

Comment: The code works fine for me, maybe your input is the problem? edit: Maybe you are inputing "3,7" instead of "3.7" ?

Comment: I wrote 100.23 for the miles i am running in intellij.

Comment: OK... what about the other `read.nextDouble`s?

Comment: So you type "100.23", press enter, and it immediately raises an exception?

Comment: Thanks in mine the comma is acting as point I just tried and it Happened. Thanks again

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, strip your code down to the least needed to show your problem.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the code works fine here. check what you type . you may type a comma instead of a dot

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line before asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score -1):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()):

> Throws:
>
> - `InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range

Basically, you're inputting something that is not a number.